# Upgrade sudoer to 1.8.1 or above

Tags: 10.04, sudo

What's the best way to upgrade the sudo from 1.7.2 by default to 1.8.1 or above? I've an auditing program that required sudo 1.8.1 or above. I'm using Ubuntu 10.04. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What auditing program? The creator of that program might have a sollution for older Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 0):

In general you can use newer versions by installing the package for it from a newer Ubuntu. Precise uses 1.8.3 so [download the package](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo) for [that release](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sudo/1.8.3p1-1ubuntu3.3) and install it.

The package is rather vital for a correct working of Ubuntu so prepare for things to break. If your system is a production server I would advice to first test this on another server where you can play and break.

If at any way possible I would also consider upgrading/updating to the new LTS to prevent similar problems in the future.